# Functional Interface with default behavior with Serializable

Tags: java, interface, compiler-warnings, serializable, default-method

When an Interface with no default method extends Serializable everythings works fine.
But When a default method for that interface comes in picture we have a warning that says:

> MyInterface.java: serializable class MyInterface has no definition
>   of serialVersionUID

It got intersting when I change that interface to a abstract class. The error disappears.

To sum up the warning happening table is as below:

```
|----------------------------|------------------|
|            Type            |      WARNING     |
|----------------------------|------------------|
| interface with no defaults |         NO       |
|----------------------------|------------------|
| interface with defaults    |        YES       |
|----------------------------|------------------|
| abstract class             |         NO       |
|----------------------------|------------------|
```

Is there any reason for that or it's just a bug?

Comment: This only happens when you use `javac -Xlint`. And -X options are Oracle-specific and not part of any Java specification. This warning appears on 1.8u152 and 9.0.1.

Comment: Do not have such problem when I tried in Eclipse

Comment: @DodgyCodeException Yes. I'm using oracle jdk and I'm using -Xlint. It still is an odd bahaviour.

Comment: Thanks for filing a bug on this. It's now tracked as [JDK-8191637](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8191637). It is indeed a bug that you get a missing serialVersionUID warning on an interface. Since an interface is never serialized, it's pointless for it to have a serialVersionUID. However, you say that an abstract class does not generate a missing svuid warning. For me it does, and it should. Under what circumstances does javac not issue the warning for an abstract class?

Comment: Ah. JDK 7 would not issue a warning for serializable abstract classes that were missing serialVersionUID. See [JDK-6356530](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6356530). That was fixed, but where are still cases where javac issues the warning when it shouldn't and possibly doesn't issue a warning when it should. We'll fix them in [JDK-8191637](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8191637).

Comment: Hmm, was this really fixed? I'm still able to reproduce it with 8u252.